# caret lda2 parameters values

Tags: r, r-caret

In order to get the possible values of lda2 parameters I run

```
getModelInfo("lda2")[[1]]$grid
```

and got

```
function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") data.frame(dimen = 1:min(ncol(x), length(levels(y)) - 1))
```

therefore there's only one parameter: dimen

In my case

```
ncol(x)=32 
levels(y)=2
```

so

`min(ncol(x), length(levels(y)) - 1) = 1`

Does this mean that dimen can only take the **1** value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The `:` generates a sequence of values. `dimen` is therefore between `1` and `min(ncol(x), length(levels(y)) - 1)`. The exact values that `dimen` can take depends on your input data.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- mtcars %>%
     select(-carb)
y <- mtcars$carb %>% as.factor

dimen <- 1:min(ncol(x), length(levels(y)) - 1)
dimen
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks @JanLauGe but I don't understand, because if I have a classification problem with two outcome levels for example (yes, no) then dimen<- 1: min(ncol(x), 2-1) so it only varies from 1 to 1

Comment: Oh, yes, for binomial classification you would only use one discriminant function. That makes sense, because you are looking for the one line in n-dimensional space that best separates two point clusters. I think this also means that you could use `lda` instead of `lda2`, but run both methods for your data and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JanLauGe